# How do I know my Foundry Job is using AQE?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-code-workbooks

I hear people mention this AQE feature sometimes and I'm wondering how to verify if my job is using it or not.  I'm running transformations both in Code Repositories and Code Workbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is noted in the `Environment` details tab of a job.

1. Navigate to Builds page

[image: Builds page]

2. Find your running Build in the `Build` page. Click on it.

[image: Find your Build]

2. Find your relevant Job inside your Build's page.  Click on it.
3. In the expanded view under your Job, click on the `Spark Details` button

[image: Spark Details]

4. Click on the `Environment` tab

[image: Environment Tab]

5. Look for a row for `adaptiveExecutionEnabled`.  If `true`, you are using AQE.  If `false` then you are not.

[image: AQE Enabled]