# How do I identify that my Foundry job's stage has skew?

Tags: apache-spark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-code-workbooks, foundry-contour

I have a job running with a stage that seems to be taking a long time.  I've heard that this might be due to something called 'skew'.

How do I know if I'm being impacted by this?

I know this is commonly associated with joins, windows, and other operations that incur shuffles but I don't know how to identify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Spark Details like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70792919/how-do-i-know-my-foundry-job-is-using-aqe)
2. Identify either currently running stage or your slowest stage overall
3. Click on this stage's row to reveal Stage Details button [image: Stage Details button]
4. Click on Stage Details button
5. Look at metrics of stage at the top of your screen.  If you see a smaller number of tasks running significantly longer than the others, this means you have skew [image: Skew]
6. If you click on the slowest task, you'll find the task highlighted in the overview below, which will indicate the sizes of inputs / outputs.  [image: Skew Details]

In the above example, there is a task in this job + stage that is taking orders of magnitude longer to run because its input size is orders of magnitude larger than the other tasks.

This is the definition of a skewed task / skewed stage.

If you want to know what value is causing this task to be slow, check out the guidance over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71149292/how-do-i-identify-the-value-of-a-skewed-task-of-my-foundry-job)