# How do I identify the value of a skewed task of my Foundry job?

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-python-transform, foundry-contour

I've looked into my job and have [identified that I do indeed have a skewed task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71148720/how-do-i-identify-that-my-foundry-jobs-stage-has-skew).  How do I determine what the actual value is inside this task that is causing the skew?

My Python Transforms code looks like this:

```py
from transforms.api import Input, Output, transform


@transform(
  ...
)
def my_compute_function(...):
  ...
  df = df.join(df_2, ["joint_col"])
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Theory

**Skew problems originate from anything that causes an exchange in your job.  Things that cause exchanges include but are not limited to: `join`s, `window`s, `groupBy`s.**

These operations result in data movement across your Executors based upon the found values inside the DataFrames used.  This means that when a used DataFrame has many repeated values on the column dictating the exchange, those rows all end up in the same task, thus increasing its size.

## Example

Let's consider the following example distribution of data for your join:

```
DataFrame 1 (df1)

| col_1 | col_2 |
|-------|-------|
| key_1 | 1     |
| key_1 | 2     |
| key_1 | 3     |
| key_1 | 1     |
| key_1 | 2     |
| key_2 | 1     |

DataFrame 2 (df2)

| col_1 | col_2 |
|-------|-------|
| key_1 | 1     |
| key_1 | 2     |
| key_1 | 3     |
| key_1 | 1     |
| key_2 | 2     |
| key_3 | 1     |
```

These DataFrames when joined together on `col_1` will have the following data distributed across the executors:

- Task 1:

  - Receives: 5 rows of `key_1` from df1
  - Receives: 4 rows of `key_1` from df2
  - Total Input: 9 rows of data sent to task_1
  - Result: 5 * 4 = **20 rows of output data**
- Task 2:

  - Receives: 1 row of `key_2` from df1
  - Receives: 1 row of `key_2` from df2
  - Total Input: 2 rows of data sent to task_2
  - Result: 1 * 1 = **1 rows of output data**
- Task 3:

  - Receives: 1 row of `key_3` from df2
  - Total Input: 1 rows of data sent to task_3
  - Result: 1 * 0 = **0 rows of output data** (missed key; no key found in df1)

If you therefore look at the counts of input and output rows per task, you'll see that Task 1 has far more data than the others.  **This task is skewed**.

## Identification

The question now becomes how we identify that `key_1` is the culprit of the skew since this isn't visible in Spark (the underlying engine powering the join).

If we look at the above example, we see that all we need to know is the actual counts per key of the *joint column*.  This means we can:

1. Aggregate each side of the join on the joint key and count the rows per key
2. Multiply the counts of each side of the join to determine the output row counts

The easiest way to do this is by opening the Analysis (Contour) tool in Foundry and performing the following analysis:

1. Add `df1` as input to a first path
2. Add `Pivot Table` board, using `col_1` as the rows, and `Row count` as the aggregate

   [image: Pivot]
3. Click the `⇄ Switch to pivoted data` button

   [image: Switch]
4. Use the `Multi-Column Editor` board to keep only `col_1` and the `COUNT` column.  Prefix each of them with `df1_`, resulting in an output from the path which is only `df1_col_1` and `df1_COUNT`.
5. Add `df2` as input to a second path
6. Add `Pivot Table` board, again using `col_1` as the rows, and `Row count` as the aggregate

   [image: Pivot]
7. Click the `⇄ Switch to pivoted data` button

   [image: Switch]
8. Use the `Multi-Column Editor` board to keep only `col_1` and the `COUNT` column.  Prefix each of them with `df2_`, resulting in an output from the path which is only `df2_col_1` and `df2_COUNT`.
9. Create a third path, using the result of the first path (`df1_col_1` and `df1_COUNT1`)
10. Add a `Join` board, making the right side of the join the result of the second path (`df2_col_1` and `df2_col_1`).  Ensure the join type is `Full join`

    [image: Join]
11. Add all columns from the right side (you don't need to add a prefix, all the columns are unique
12. Configure the join board to join on `df1_col_1` equals `df2_col_1`

    [image: Join condition]
13. Add an `Expression` board to create a new column, `output_row_count` which multiplies the two `COUNT` columns together

    [image: Multiply]
14. Add a `Sort` board that sorts on `output_row_count` descending

    [image: Sort]
15. If you now preview the resultant data, you will have a sorted list of keys from both sides of the join that are causing the skew

    [image: preview]

Comment: Should we do this analysis before doing each join operation in code repository ?