# Hanging Foundry job; why does it seem stuck on a stage?

Tags: apache-spark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-code-workbooks

I see from my job overview page that my job appears stuck on one of the stages (most others have taken a reasonable amount of time, one of them is much slower).

What does it mean when one of my stages is taking so long to finish?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely thing you're suffering from is **skew**.

Skew is defined as an imbalance of work done by a Spark stage, namely that certain tasks for whatever reason take much longer to compute than others.

It's important to [verify that your job actually has skew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71148720/how-do-i-identify-that-my-foundry-jobs-stage-has-skew) and not just assume this is the culprit.

One of the most common reasons for skew is an imbalance of distribution of keys for a shuffle.  An example of this is when a join has a large count of rows for keys on both side of a join.  There's some ways you can [verify this distribution problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71149292/how-do-i-identify-the-value-of-a-skewed-task-of-my-foundry-job).

You might get unlucky sometimes and have a task that is both longer-running and kicked off at the very end of your stage.  When this happens, you'll observe particularly slow stage execution times; sometimes you get lucky and it gets kicked off first.  In this example, the slower 5 sec task is the skewed task.  [image: Unlucky Task]