# How do I know if my Foundry job is using static vs. dynamic allocation?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-code-workbooks

I heard someone mention that jobs can run in static allocation or something called dynamic allocation.  How do I know which one my job is using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70792919/how-do-i-know-my-foundry-job-is-using-aqe) to find the `Environment` tab, you'll notice a row that indicates `dynamicAllocationEnabled`.  If it's `true`, you're using dynamic allocation.  If `false`, you are using static allocation.

You can read about the benefits and drawbacks of each [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70381697/when-would-i-prefer-to-run-a-job-in-static-allocation-vs-dynamic-allocation)