# How many executors is my Foundry job using?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-code-workbooks

I can see the parallelism of my job in the Spark Details page, but I wonder how many Executors my job is actually running with.

Where can I see this?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the same methodology to find the `Environment` tab noted over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70792919/how-do-i-know-my-foundry-job-is-using-aqe), you'll find an entry on that page for the number of executors used.

Depending on your environment, you may find that `dynamicAllocation` is `true`, in which case you'll have a `minExecutors` and a `maxExecutors` setting noted, which is used as the 'bounds' of your job.  You'll have any number of executors in that range depending on if you're using [static allocation or dynamic allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70932066/how-do-i-know-if-my-foundry-job-is-using-static-vs-dynamic-allocation).

If `dynamicAllocation` is `false`, then you'll see an `executorInstances` entry, with the count listed there.