# How do I ensure my Foundry job is running with static allocation?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I can [tell whether my job is using static allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70932066/how-do-i-know-if-my-foundry-job-is-using-static-vs-dynamic-allocation), however I want to actually change my job to use it.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your compute function has the `configure` decorator and includes the `STATIC_ALLOCATION` profile like so:

```py
from transforms.api import Input, Output, configure, transform


@configure(profile=["STATIC_ALLOCATION"])
@transform(
  ...
)
def my_compute_function(...):
  ...
```